# How to copy multiple events along with their actions in Construct2

Tags: html, construct-2

I have an event sheet named "EVENT SHEET 1", there are  events in it.  I want to copy these events to "EVENT SHEET 2".

When I do this by selecting desired events, all the events get copied into a single event.

How do I paste the events so they maintain their original structure?

Comment: Why is this down-voted?  Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the events from EVENT SHEET 1 in the 2 you should go to EVENT SHEET 2, right click and include EVENT SHEET 1. That'd do the trick without the need to copy and duplicate code.

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I'm using the same sprites in both the layouts, and if I include an event sheet completely, the sprite effects also apply to the sprites in the new layout.

Comment: Create an event sheet with just the code you need and import it in both event sheets.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I believe the answer has to do with a confusing aspect of Construct 2's UI.

In each event row depending on where you click you can select the Condition, the Actions, or the **entire Event**.

It sound like just the conditions were selected, shift-click to select all of them, and then when pasted, they were all inserted as the Conditions to a new Event.

What you want instead is to **click just to the left of the Condition** and you will see the **entire row (Event) highlighted** instead of just the Condition.

Copy and past that and the conditions will stay separated.